# Is it possible to echo a specific cell from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a column 'k1'. In the table there's a lot of rows all attached to the id of the user who submitted them. How can I echo them on my site in a specific place?
I called

`SELECT * FROM table`

but if I echo `rows ['k1']` I can't control which row it echoes? Make sense? 
Can you help me?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: `WHERE id = <something>`

Comment: You need to loop through the recordset to find the row you wish to echo back.

Comment: Even better to filter the recordsets with a query, no? @durbnpoisn

Comment: Jay - I need all the rows but in different places on the site :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

$k1 = Array();


//Fetch the query
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{

//Column from the databases

$k1[] = $row['k1'];


}
```

You now have all of the K1 rows in an array to grab which one you want by an index number

or.....

```
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?");
```

if an ID Exists

Comment: But I would like to select the given row by the User Id.. So fx i write a username and the echo the 'k1-row' to that username. Then further down I write another username and echo the row to that.